# Does O(1) mean an algorithm takes one step to execute a required task?

Tags: complexity-theory

I thought it meant it takes a constant amount of time to run. Is that different than one step?

Comment: It means it takes a constant amount of time. How many steps are involved is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this question would be asked better on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And O(n) means a constant time for each step.

Answer (score 1):

It means that even if you increase the size of whatever the algorithm is operating on, the number of calculations required to run remains the same.

More specifically it means that the number of calculations doesn't get larger than some constant no matter how big the input gets.

In contrast, O(N) means that if the size of the input is N, the number of steps required is at most a constant times N, no matter how big N gets.

So for example (in python code since that's probably easy for most to interpret):

```
def f(L, index):  #L a list, index an integer
    x = L[index]
    y=2*L[index]
    return x + y
```

then even though `f` has several calculations within it, the time taken to run is the same regardless of how long the list `L` is.  However,

```
def g(L): #L a list
    return sum(L)
```

This will be O(N) where N is the length of list `L`.  Even though there is only a single calculation written, the system has to add all N entries together.  So it has to do at least one step for each entry.  So as N increases, the number of steps increases proportional to N.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) is a *class of functions*. Namely, it includes functions bounded by a constant.

We say that an algorithm has the complexity of O(1) iff the amount of steps it takes, as a function of the size of the input, is bounded by a(n arbirtary) constant. This function can be a constant, or it can grow, or behave chaotically, or undulate as a sine wave. As long as it never exceeds some predefined constant, it's O(1).

For more information, see [Big O notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already tried to answer it, it simply means..

No matter how many mangoes you've got in a box, it'll always take you the same amount of time to eat 1 mango. How you plan on eating it is irrelevant, there maybe a single step or you might go through multiple steps and slice it nicely to consume it.